# A strange phenomenon to initialize struct with GNU C++'s Compound Literals (maybe UB?)

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, c++17, undefined-behavior

```cpp
#include <cstdio> // GCC C++17
struct node{int x;}a[5];
signed main()
{
    int i=1;
    a[++i]=(node){i};
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)printf("%d ",a[i].x);
}
```

Since C++17, `a[++i]=i` is not a UB.

According to Sequenced-before rules ,

`a[++i]=i` is equivalent to `a[i+1]=i , i+=1`. **(in C++17)**

But why does the above code run output `0 0 2 0 0` instead of `0 0 1 0 0`?

When I try :

```cpp
#include <cstdio> // GCC C++17
struct node{int x;node(){x=0;}node(int _x){x=_x;}}a[5];
signed main()
{
    int i=1;
    a[++i]=node(i);
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)printf("%d ",a[i].x);
}
```

there is no such problem , output `0 0 1 0 0`.

I read the GNU documentation but I can’t find valid information.

So what is going on?

Comment: Compound literals is not part of C++17, so you might turn first example to aggregate initialization (which is still problematic for gcc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3MjK83aG8))

Comment: And for the fixed version, gcc warns erroneously about sequence point [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s5bdMos9o)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks but i found another problem：

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1f7e53zE3)

It also reported [-Werror=sequence-point] under g++17. 

Why?

Comment: I would say gcc bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a compiler bug. I tried your code with clang 13.0.0 and it produced the output you wanted. Same with icx 3.0.

But as have been pointed out in comments, compound literals are not a part of C++17 standard, so you cannot really expect this to work at all by just looking at the standard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's a bug. When writing `A = B` where `A` is an object, you are calling the function `operator=()` generated by the compiler and the first parameter of this function is `this`. So you should look for the evaluation order of function parameters (which is undefined).